# ?MASS in R doesn't give the rsult I am willing to have

Tags: r

I have tried the following code

```
install.packages("MASS")
library(MASS)
?MASS
No documentation for ‘MASS’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??MASS’
```

It seems R could not show the result I want, any idea about the mistake?

Comment: Try `help(package='MASS')`.

Comment: `MASS` is a base package, you don't have to `install.packages("MASS")`, it comes with every installation of R.

Comment: Got it. thx @RuiBarradas

Comment: Sorry for the noise. What I wrote was not what I intended.

Comment: What's the result you want? Packages don't always have a help page for the overall package; often there are just help pages for individual functions, classes, datasets, etc. In this case, there isn't a package-level help page